# Geonetwork database whit Ldap Connection error

Tags: database, ldap, openldap, geonetwork, georchestra

I'm trying to connect my ldap with the geonetwork database but every time I log in it doesn't show the administrator button. Then I check the database and it is empty. I am using GeOrchestra 13.09 in a localhost enviroment, the geoserver and mapfishapp are running well and they log in without a problem.

My `config-security.properties` is

```
Core security properties
logout.success.url=/index.html
passwordSalt=secret-hash-salt=

# LDAP Connection Settings
ldap.base.provider.url=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.base.dn=dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo
ldap.security.principal=cn=admin,dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo
ldap.security.credentials=geobolivia

ldap.base.search.base=ou=users
ldap.base.dn.pattern=uid={0},${ldap.base.search.base}
#ldap.base.dn.pattern=mail={0},${ldap.base.search.base}

# Define if groups and profile information are imported from LDAP. If not, local database is used.
# When a new user connect first, the default profile is assigned. A user administrator can update
# privilege information.
ldap.privilege.import=true
ldap.privilege.export=true

ldap.privilege.create.nonexisting.groups=false

# Define the way to extract profiles and privileges from the LDAP
# 1. Define one attribute for the profile and one for groups in config-security-overrides.properties

# 2. Define one attribute for the privilege and define a custom pattern (use LDAPUserDetailsContextMapperWithPa$
ldap.privilege.pattern=
#ldap.privilege.pattern=CAT_(.*)_(.*)
ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.group=1
ldap.privilege.pattern.idx.profil=2

# 3. Define custom location for extracting group and role (no support for group/role combination) (use LDAPUser$
#ldap.privilege.search.group.attribute=cn
#ldap.privilege.search.group.object=ou=groups
#ldap.privilege.search.group.query=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={0})(cn=EL_*))
#ldap.privilege.search.group.pattern=EL_(.*)
#ldap.privilege.search.privilege.attribute=cn
#ldap.privilege.search.privilege.object=ou=groups
#ldap.privilege.search.privilege.query=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={0})(cn=SV_*))
#ldap.privilege.search.privilege.pattern=SV_(.*)

ldap.privilege.search.group.attribute=cn
ldap.privilege.search.group.object=ou=groups
ldap.privilege.search.group.query=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={1})(cn=EL_*))
ldap.privilege.search.group.pattern=EL_(.*)
ldap.privilege.search.privilege.attribute=cn
ldap.privilege.search.privilege.object=ou=groups
ldap.privilege.search.privilege.query=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={1})(cn=SV_ADMIN))
ldap.privilege.search.privilege.pattern=SV_(.*)

# Run LDAP sync every day at 23:30

# Run LDAP sync every day at 23:30
#ldap.sync.cron=0 30 23 * * ?
ldap.sync.cron=0 * * * * ?
#ldap.sync.cron=0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
ldap.sync.startDelay=60000
ldap.sync.user.search.base=${ldap.base.search.base}
ldap.sync.user.search.filter=(&(objectClass=*)(mail=*@*)(givenName=*))
ldap.sync.user.search.attribute=uid
ldap.sync.group.search.base=ou=groups
ldap.sync.group.search.filter=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=EL_*))
ldap.sync.group.search.attribute=cn
ldap.sync.group.search.pattern=EL_(.*)

# CAS properties
cas.baseURL=https://localhost:8443/cas
cas.ticket.validator.url=${cas.baseURL}
cas.login.url=${cas.baseURL}/login
cas.logout.url=${cas.baseURL}/logout?url=${geonetwork.https.url}/

<import resource="config-security-cas.xml"/>
<import resource="config-security-cas-ldap.xml"/>

# either the hardcoded url to the server
# or if has the form  it will be replaced with
# the server details from the server configuration
geonetwork.https.url=https://localhost/geonetwork-private/
#geonetwork.https.url=https://geobolivia.gob.bo:443
#geonetwork.https.url=https://localhost:443
```

The `geonetwork.log` shows these results:

```
2014-03-11 13:41:00,004 DEBUG [geonetwork.ldap] - LDAPSynchronizerJob starting ...
2014-03-11 13:41:00,006 DEBUG [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource] - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:389/dc=geobolivia,dc=gob,dc=bo'
2014-03-11 13:41:00,008 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resourceManager'
2014-03-11 13:41:00,026 DEBUG [geonetwork.ldap] - LDAPSynchronizerJob done.
2014-03-11 13:41:26,429 INFO  [geonetwork.lucene] - Done running PurgeExpiredSearchersTask. 0 versions still cached.
2014-03-11 13:41:56,430 INFO  [geonetwork.lucene] - Done running PurgeExpiredSearchersTask. 0 versions still cached.
```

and the that appear in the geonetwork.log is

```
2014-03-11 13:44:06,426 INFO  [jeeves.service] - Dispatching : xml.search.keywords
2014-03-11 13:44:06,427 ERROR [jeeves.service] - Exception when executing service
2014-03-11 13:44:06,427 ERROR [jeeves.service] -  (C) Exc : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The thesaurus external.theme.inspire-service-taxonomy does not exist, there for the query cannot be excuted: 'Query [query=SELECT DISTINCT id,uppc,lowc,broader,spa_prefLabel,spa_note FROM {id} rdf:type {skos:Concept},[{id} gml:BoundedBy {} gml:upperCorner {uppc}],[{id} gml:BoundedBy {} gml:lowerCorner {lowc}],[{id} skos:broader {broader}],[{id} skos:prefLabel {spa_prefLabel} WHERE lang(spa_prefLabel) LIKE "es" IGNORE CASE],[{id} skos:scopeNote {spa_note} WHERE lang(spa_note) LIKE "es" IGNORE CASE] WHERE (spa_prefLabel LIKE "***" IGNORE CASE OR id LIKE "*") LIMIT 35 USING NAMESPACE skos=<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>,gml=<http://www.opengis.net/gml#>, interpreter=KeywordResultInterpreter]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of GeoNetwork currently used in geOrchestra does not show the "administration" button on its first page. You have to fire a search, then in "other actions" menu on the top right, you should be able to get to the administration interface. We know that it is not very intuitive, but it should change in the next months (we recently planned an upgrade of GeoNetwork before the end of the year).

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve it? I think in your config-security.properties, at this place `ldap.base.dn.pattern=uid={0},${ldap.base.search.base}`
you need to replace {0} with the username typed in the sign-in screen of geonetwork